# Detecting a Google Instant Search and extracting a search keyword from the URL

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome

What's a **reliable** way to detect if the Google search URL is from an Google Instant page and not from typical search and extract a keyword(s) from that URL?

How should one differentiate these two URLs? Is there a standard URL/Query String format for instant search?

Typical Search Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world

Typical search simply passes keyword(s) in a `q` parameter of a query string.

Instant Search Example: https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=hello+world+again&pbx=1&oq=hello+world+again&aq=f&aqi=g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1355l3667l0l3832l17l15l0l2l2l1l255l3081l2-14l16l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=682774cd339f5d00&biw=1316&bih=682

During an instant search parameters are appended after a hash (#). In this case is it reliable to detect if URL contains a hash and detect `q` parameter after a hash position?

**I'm trying to retrieve a current keyword(s) from the search URL.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small function that extracts `q` parameter from the query string.

Tested and works perfectly with URLs provided above... I'm still testing it across various other URLs and if I notice some bug I'll fix the function and update it here...

Enjoy:

```
var parse_google_url = function (url)
{
    var hash_position = url.indexOf('#'),
    query_string = url.substr(hash_position === -1 ? url.indexOf('?') : hash_position);
    return decodeURI((RegExp('q=(.+?)(&|$)').exec(query_string) || [,null])[1]);
}
```